# FileInfo - Select one File out of one FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, compare, fileinfo

i have two FileInfo[] Array's and i want compare the Files with identical Names about their File Size and Last Modified Date. But how can i select a File out of a FileInfo[] with a specific Name?

My Code doesnt work, because i cant use FileInfo.Select to get a new FileInfo out. Any clues?

```
        foreach (FileInfo origFile in fiArrOri6)
        {
            FileInfo destFile = fiArrNew6.Select(file => file.Name == origFile.Name);
            if (origFile.Length != destFile.Length || origFile.LastWriteTime != destFile.LastWriteTime)
            {
                //do sth.
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help :)

btw. Any other charming solution for this Problem would be great. 
btw. #2 : does someone has good learning material for FileInfo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [FirstOrDefault that takes a filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx)

```
FileInfo destFile = fiArrNew6.FirstOrDefault(file => file.Name == origFile.Name);
```

Or, if you don't want the default, you can use the equivalent [First that takes a filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx)

```
FileInfo destFile = fiArrNew6.First(file => file.Name == origFile.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

`destFile` is not a FileInfo, it is a linq query.  Change its name to something like `fileQuery` and then

```
var fileQuery = fiArrNew6.Where(file => file.Name == origFile.Name);
var destFile = fileQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if (destFile != null)
    //...
```

Bonus tip: avoid names like `fiArrNew6`; they're confusing.  Descriptive names like `newFiles` are easier to read, and they allow you to change your code without having to rename your variables.

Comment: +1 Definitely agree with your bonus tip :) I always say concise is not short only it is short AND descriptive. Emphasis should be more on descriptive

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Select` into a `Where`:

```
FileInfo destFile = fiArrNew6.Where(file => file.Name == origFile.Name).First();
```

The `Where` will return an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`, using `First` with that will ensure the first such occurrence is used (if there are none, it will throw an exception).

Comment: `Where` will return `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`, not `FileInfo`.